# is it possible to restrict a token to one device ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, access-token

in .NET environment -Token based authentication- is it possible to restrict a token to one device so that someone cannot copy the token and perform requests using that access token on another device?

Comment: How would you know what device it came from? I'd say potentially yes...

Comment: I was thinking that Tokens can be tied to a specific client ID (application)
or  Something unique with a particular device

Comment: You need to keep on a server database the token with some other info from the browser, and check that connection on each request.

Comment: You are probably looking for [client certificate authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2015/05/27/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/) where you issue a unique certificate to each user.

Comment: The "general" answer to this is **yes**. The "how" is the part that would make this too broad. You can look into APIs out there that require some form of _client_ authentication - which uniquely identifies the _caller_ (aka "client"/"device").

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

1- The naive solution is, you get the User-Agent from request header as well as client ip address, concatenate them with the token and encrypt it with a SecretKey and return the whole string as a new token to the client, so every time client sends a request to server you have to decrypt the token based on the SecretKey and check the data with the coming request ip address and User-Agent. so in case if any one copy the token it will not match with the headers or ip. but if the client pass the entire header properly and has the same ip address as the original client you are hacked!

2- The safest solution is [client certificate authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2015/05/27/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/) as NightOwl888 mentioned